# How do I get ROS to use Pillow?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, osx, macosx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Homebrew to install ROS - Hydro on my 10.9 Mac. While using ROS' wiki for installing hydro, 2.1.2 causes an error specifically pertaining to installing PIL. I know such has been replaced with *Pillow,* and have already used such before. My question is, how do I get ROS to just use *Pillow* instead of **PIL**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188055/how-do-i-get-ros-to-use-pillow?/) by [warsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/19865/warsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have no clue how interchangeable PIL and Pillow are, so no idea how easy it would be to make the code depending on PIL use Pillow. I think your easier bet is just installing PIL.

I assume you are getting a freetype related compilation error? This has been discussed before, you will likely be successful with the following sequence of commands:

```
ln -s /usr/local/include/freetype2 /usr/local/include/freetype
pip install -U PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL
rm /usr/local/include/freetype
```

**Update:** According to William in the comments below this is a better way to work around the freetype issue:

```
CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/freetype2" pip install -U PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL
```

**EDIT**: you might need `sudo pip` instead of `pip`

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-07-28**:
We ran into issues where ogre would not compile with that symbolic link, it somehow created a circular or incorrect include problem with freetype. I had previously done something like `CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/freetype2" pip install ...` and that allowed pip to build `PIL`, without permanently changing the system. I'm not sure that is right, but I'll just look around on the internet for that.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-07-28**:
Here: https://github.com/osrf/homebrew-simulation/issues/6#issuecomment-38644605 You have to include the X11 version of freetype in the `CFLAGS`.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-07-28**:
Another option is to just do `cd /tmp && ln -s . /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype` and then invoking pip, again this prevent permanent modification of the system.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-29**:
Is there any advantage of `CFLAGS= ... pip install` vs my suggestion to create and remove the link?
rosdep should maybe be capable of customizing the pip command. Something like `prepend_install: 'CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/freetype2"'` or `install_env: {CFLAGS:"-I/usr/local/include/freetype2}`

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-07-31**:
@demmeln no probably not, I didn't see that you were removing it afterwards.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-31**:
Ah OK makes sense